Do you have to await a ValueTask?
The title says it all:
The specs explicitly say that you must never await a ValueTask more than once - because in particular in the truly asynchronous case, the backing state machine may be pooled and recycled for other ValueTasks after awaiting it.
But what about awaiting less than once - i.e., never? Could this cause any issues? For example, would the backing state still be able to be returned to the pool even if nobody awaited the result?
async Task IsThisLegal()
{
  var _ = SomeValueTask();
  await Task.Delay(10);
  // The value task would have completed by now, but we're not awaiting it. Is that ok?
}

async ValueTask<bool> SomeValueTask()
{
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  return true;
}


What are you trying to achieve? Is it a fire and forget call? Do you intend to call .Result on the value task later?


Do you have to await a ValueTask?

No. Not nessesarily.

Never awaiting. Could this cause any issues?

Yes, potentially.

General issues with fire-and-forget, like not knowing if an exception occurred, and not knowing if the operation completed at all. For example in an ASP.NET application the worker process might be recycled at any moment, terminating abruptly any pending operations that have been launched in a fire-and-forget fashion.
Issues with concurrency. Many components are equipped with asynchronous APIs, but they do not support concurrency. If you start an asynchronous operation before the previous operation has completed, the component has undefined behavior (usually throws an exception). An example of such a component is the Stream class, equipped with ReadAsync and WriteAsync APIs. By not awaiting the ValueTask, you can't know when it's safe to proceed with the next operation on the same instance of the component.
Issues with memory efficiency. APIs that return ValueTasks are frequently implemented with an IValueTaskSource backing state that is pooled and reused, minimized the allocations and reducing the pressure on the garbage collector. By not awaiting the ValueTask, the component has no way to know that the ValueTask has been consumed, so it can't reuse the backing state. As a result it will create a new backing state for the next operation. There is no formal way to tell the component that "I promise to never await this ValueTask". All IValueTaskSource implementations that I've seen use the GetResult method as an indicator that the ValueTask has been consumed. The GetResult is called automatically by the .NET infrastructure, whenever a ValueTask is awaited.


Thank you. This may almost warrant a new question, but is it always GetResult() that would be the destructive operation? Meaning, say you register GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => SomeCallback()), then some callback waits ten hours and only then calls GetResult() - that would be a stupid, but legal operation because waiting for completion would not guarantee not to invalidate the task for further operations, only draining the result afterwards would? (strongly suppose that is the case, but hard to find documentation here)

@​Bogey I don't think that you can return to the pool an IValueTaskSource instance before the GetResult is called, because in that case the instance might be assigned to a different asynchronous operation prematurely. The GetResult call is not purely decorative. Its purpose is to expose the exception that might be stored inside a ValueTask, by throwing it. If you return the backing state to the pool, this information might be lost (it will certainly be lost if the implementation calls Reset before returning a consumed IValueTaskSource to the pool).

Documentation: ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<TResult>.Reset, and source code.

As you pointed out fire-and-forgetting a ValueTask returning method is not explicitly covered by the online documentation:

A ValueTask instance may only be awaited once, and consumers
may not read Result until the instance has completed.
The following operations should never be performed on a
ValueTask instance:

Awaiting the instance multiple times.
Calling AsTask multiple times.
Using .Result or .GetAwaiter().GetResult() when the operation hasn't yet completed, or using them multiple times.
Using more than one of these techniques to consume the instance.

If you do any of the above, the results are undefined.

All of these limitations stem from the option to have IValueTaskSource instances used for the construction of the ValueTask. It's an interface that anybody can implement very easily by making use of ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore in the way  Stephen Toub proposed:

To make it easier ... on anyone else that wants to do
similar things, we should provide an implementation of the core
logic needed for this interface, such that implementing the interface
is then as simple as delegating to the helpers provided.

For example:
public class SimpleValueTaskSourceImplementer<T> : IValueTaskSource<T> {
    public ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T> manualResetTask = new(); // public for debugging purposes
    
    public T GetResult(short token) {
        return manualResetTask.GetResult(token);
    }
    public ValueTaskSourceStatus GetStatus(short token) {
        return manualResetTask.GetStatus(token);
    }
    public void OnCompleted(Action<object> continuation, object state, short token, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags) {
        manualResetTask.OnCompleted(continuation, state, token, flags);
    }
}

Then we can use it in this demo class returning ValueTask<int>
public class AsyncClass {

    SimpleValueTaskSourceImplementer<int> valueTaskSource = new();
    int m_counter = 42;
    
    public ValueTask<int> GetNextValueAsync() {
        valueTaskSource.manualResetTask.Reset(); 
        short version = valueTaskSource.manualResetTask.Version;

        Interlocked.Increment(ref m_counter);
        var captureCounter = m_counter;
        Task.Run(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            valueTaskSource.manualResetTask.SetResult(captureCounter);
        });

        return new ValueTask<int>(valueTaskSource, version);
    }
}

Let's test it with await:
async Task Main() {
    var asyncClass = new AsyncClass();
    var result1 = await asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result1); // 43
    var result2 = await asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result2); // 44
}

It works.
But what if we do .Result and .GetAwaiter().GetResult() which would be undefined behavior according to the docs?
var asyncClass = new AsyncClass();
try {
    var result1 = asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync().Result;
} catch (InvalidOperationException ex ) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
}

try {
    var result1 = asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
} catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
}

We get exceptions but it's supposed to be undefined behavior anyway.
Now if the developer of the SimpleValueTaskSourceImplementer<T> and the AsyncClass is satisfied enough and ships this, your case could become problematic:
var asyncClass = new AsyncClass();
_ = asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync(); // fire and forget
var result1 = await asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
Console.WriteLine(result1);

We will get a bit of a race condition so the result would be either 43 or 44 and on top of that we get an unhandled InvalidOperationException in our Task.Run lambda. The first lambda sets the results (could be the fire-and-forget one), and the second one is facing a completed task which is invalid to call SetResult again on.
 Task.Run(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        valueTaskSource.manualResetTask.SetResult(captureCounter);
    });

Of course, the developer could have created a pool of valueTaskSources instead of just one, then the problem wouldn't have occurred:
public class SimpleValueTaskSourceImplementer<T> : IValueTaskSource<T> {
    public ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore<T> manualResetTask = new();
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; } = true;

    public T GetResult(short token) {
        this.IsAvailable = true;
        return manualResetTask.GetResult(token);
    }
    public ValueTaskSourceStatus GetStatus(short token) {
        return manualResetTask.GetStatus(token);
    }
    public void OnCompleted(Action<object> continuation, object state, short token, ValueTaskSourceOnCompletedFlags flags) {
        manualResetTask.OnCompleted(continuation, state, token, flags);
    }
}

public class AsyncClass {
    public List<SimpleValueTaskSourceImplementer<int>> listValueTaskSources =
     new List<SimpleValueTaskSourceImplementer<int>>() { new() };

    object _lockObj = new object();

    public SimpleValueTaskSourceImplementer<int> GetAvailableBackingStore() {
        lock (_lockObj) {
            var firstAvailable = listValueTaskSources.FirstOrDefault(mr => mr.IsAvailable);
            if (firstAvailable != default) {
                firstAvailable.IsAvailable = false;
                return firstAvailable;
            }

            var newCreated = new SimpleValueTaskSourceImplementer<int>();
            newCreated.IsAvailable = false;
            listValueTaskSources.Add(newCreated);
            return newCreated;
        }
    }

    int m_counter = 42;

    public ValueTask<int> GetNextValueAsync() {
        var vts = GetAvailableBackingStore();
        vts.manualResetTask.Reset();
        Interlocked.Increment(ref m_counter);
        var captureCounter = m_counter;
        Task.Run(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            vts.manualResetTask.SetResult(captureCounter);
        });

        return new ValueTask<int>(vts, vts.manualResetTask.Version);
    }
} 

So, I think that it's a potential issue, but rather unlikely in most cases.

For example, would the backing state still be able to be returned to
the pool even if nobody awaited the result?

This again is up to the implementer. But I think this comment in the source code suggests that is a common practice to return the backing state instance to the pool in the IValueTaskSource.GetResult method:

Once the result of a "ValueTask" instance has been retrieved, do not
attempt to retrieve it again.  "ValueTask" instances may be backed by
"IValueTaskSource" instances that are reusable, and such instances may
use the act of retrieving the instances result as a notification
that the instance may now be reused for a different operation.
Attempting to then reuse that same ValueTask results in undefined
behavior.

So in your case where we naturally don't call GetResult because we don't await, we could have wasted a valueTaskSources instance forever for the pool. New one has to be created, old one will probably continue live introducing a small memory leak. We can demonstrate this in our example:
var asyncClass = new AsyncClass();
Console.WriteLine(asyncClass.listValueTaskSources.Count); // start with 1
await asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
await asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
Console.WriteLine(asyncClass.listValueTaskSources.Count); // still 1
_ = asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
_ = asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
_ = asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
await asyncClass.GetNextValueAsync();
Console.WriteLine(asyncClass.listValueTaskSources.Count); // 4 unfortunately

I think this is a bit similar to old APM style IAsyncResult's leaks when EndInvoke wasn't called on them. All in all, not great, but nothing too serious in my opinion.

Also, if the task fails, this can throw in the finalizer thread.
